# Multi Direction Bullets[read]

Tags: c#, vector, xna, bullet

Been trying to code something for a while for a project im still working on for school, even though it's done.

I want to make a grenade that shoots out bullets on enemies colliding with it, but what I need help with atm is making 8 bullets shoots in all different directions at once.

here's the code my teacher gave me to do it(I asked him for help)

```
if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Texture2D pewTexture;
                pewTexture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("pew");
                game.firingSound.Play();
                //Tweak pews to shoot at mouse, rather than just going straight on the y axis.
                pew = new CPew(game, pewTexture);
                pew.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 10f + spriteVelocity;
                pew.position = position + pew.velocity * 5;

                //easy cheesy way:
                //pew.position = position;
                //pew.position.X += 15f;
                //pew.position.Y -= 20f;





                //super awesome cool way for cool people and celebrities
                pew.position = position +
                    new Vector2(
                        texture.Width * .2f - pew.texture.Width * .2f,
                        -pew.texture.Height);

                game.pews.Add(pew);

                myFiringDelay = 10;


            }
            else
            {
                if (mouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    float pi2 = (float)Math.PI * 2.0f;
                    int numShots = 10;
                    float pi2overnum = pi2 / numShots;

                    for (int i = 0; i < numShots; i++)
                    {
                        Vector2 direction = PiToVec2(pi2overnum * i);

                        //particles[i].reset(position,direction, vector2.zero, 6);
                        game.pews[i].Reset(pew.position, direction, Vector2.Zero);

                    }

           Vector2 PiToVec2(float piT)
           {
              return new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(piT), (float)Math.Cos(piT));

           }
```

apparently this will make it shoot in every direction on mouse right click but every time I try it and my game crashes straight up
Then we have a pew class which is bullets and thats what I want to be shot in those directions at the same time

you guys may not be able to help with the code i've shown you, i've spent a while looking for a way to do this but i can't seem to find anything

A former example and or source code would be really helpful, just at least another way to look at this thanks.

Showingme when it crashed, it tells me index goes out of range or is negative, if you guys could just show me base code for multidirectional bullets id be happy

Comment: If your game is crashing it would be really helpful to get the relevant output/errors from the debugger for us to be able to help you out with this

Comment: exactly put a try catch over the entire method and see what error is being thrown. Also depending on the error we will likely need to know what pews[] is. Also it is a bad idea to load your texture on every click, you may want to set this up as a reference

Comment: What line does it go out of range? What that means is if there are only 6 "pews" , you cant do pew[7]. So from what I see, when you right click it loops through 10 pews, What is there isnt 10?

Comment: look at the stacktrace and tell us what went out of range.

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is that when you try and loop through your game.pews collection you are trying to call Reset() on the first 10 items in the collection. However there appear to not be 10 pews in there. So when you get to the end and try to access the next one, that's where you get the "Index out of range" error.

For your 8 bullets from a grenade part of the question, I think you want to do something like this.

```
//Once a grenade has collided with an enemy 
float pi2 = (float)Math.PI * 2.0f;
int numShots = 8;
float pi2overnum = pi2 / numShots;

for (int i = 0; i < numShots; i++)
{
   Vector2 direction = PiToVec2(pi2overnum * i);

   pew = new CPew(game, pewTexture);

   pew.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 10f + spriteVelocity;

   //Set the position based off of the grenades last position.
   //Set the direction.
   //Set any other attributes needed.

   game.pews.Add(pew);
}
```

Now you have eight bullets moving in different directions from where the grenade exploded.
To update them and draw them I would recommend using a foreach loop so you don't have to worry about "Index out of range" errors.

```
foreach CPew pew in game.pews
{
   pew.Update();
}
```

Comment: I changed what i had in my player class, I put the foreach loop in my game.cs because it wouldnt work in player.cs and i kept getting this, Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute., does it matter that i shoot pews regularly on left click?, and if anyone could, a full example of the grenade thing from scratch would be helpful, thanks!